# Unable to apply aspect in spring MVC

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, aop, spring-aop

In my project i want to apply AOP in Spring MVC . and show the output in webpage .but unable to show and unable apply advice in the controller class.

Logging.java:-

```
import org.aspectj.lang.ProceedingJoinPoint;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Aspect;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Pointcut;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Before;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.After;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.AfterThrowing;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.AfterReturning;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Around;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Aspect
public class Logging {

   /** Following is the definition for a pointcut to select
    *  all the methods available. So advice will be called
    *  for all the methods.
    */
   @Pointcut("execution(* com.*.*(..))")
   private void selectAll(){}

   /** 
    * This is the method which I would like to execute
    * before a selected method execution.
    */
   @Before("selectAll()")
   public void beforeAdvice(){
      System.out.println("Going to setup student profile.");
   }

   /** 
    * This is the method which I would like to execute
    * after a selected method execution.
    */
   @After("selectAll()")
   public void afterAdvice(){
      System.out.println("Student profile has been setup.");
   }

   /** 
    * This is the method which I would like to execute
    * when any method returns.
    */
   @AfterReturning(pointcut = "selectAll()", returning="retVal")
   public void afterReturningAdvice(Object retVal){
      System.out.println("Returning:" + retVal.toString() );
   }

   /**
    * This is the method which I would like to execute
    * if there is an exception raised by any method.
    */
   @AfterThrowing(pointcut = "selectAll()", throwing = "ex")
   public void AfterThrowingAdvice(IllegalArgumentException ex){
      System.out.println("There has been an exception: " + ex.toString()); 
   }
  @Around("selectAll()")
   public Object aroundAdvice(ProceedingJoinPoint p) throws Throwable{
   System.out.println("Before around");
   Object o=p.proceed();
   System.out.println("After around");
   return o;
   }
   }
```

pojo class 
Student.java:-

```
public class Student {
       private Integer age;
       private String name;

       public void setAge(Integer age) {
          this.age = age;
       }
       public Integer getAge() {
          System.out.println("Age : " + age );
          return age;
       }

       public void setName(String name) {
          this.name = name;
       }
       public String getName() {
          System.out.println("Name : " + name );
          return name;
       }

    }
```

UserController.java

```
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.support.FileSystemXmlApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.Controller;





public class UserController implements Controller {

    public ModelAndView handleRequest(HttpServletRequest arg0,
            HttpServletResponse arg1) throws Exception
            {
         ApplicationContext context = 
                 new FileSystemXmlApplicationContext("C:/Users/pcuser/Desktop/zspringmvcannotation/WebContent/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml");

          Student student = (Student) context.getBean("student");

          student.getName();
          student.getAge();

          return new ModelAndView("success","student",student);
           // return new ModelAndView("/WEB-INF/jsp/success.jsp");

    }
}
```

applicationContext.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop" xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-3.0.xsd">

    <bean p:suffix=".jsp" p:prefix="/WEB-INF/jsp/"
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver"
        id="viewResolver" />



<!-- AOP support -->
        <bean id="logging" class="Logging" />
        <aop:aspectj-autoproxy>
            <aop:include name='logging' />

        </aop:aspectj-autoproxy>




    <!-- Definition for student bean -->
    <bean id="student" class="Student">
        <property name="name" value="Tapajyoti" />
        <property name="age" value="22" />
    </bean>




    <bean id="userController" class="UserController" />

    <bean id="urlMapping"
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping">

        <property name="mappings">
            <props>
                <prop key="/hello.htm">userController</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>

</beans>
```

Dispatcher-servlet.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE beans PUBLIC "-//SPRING//DTD BEAN//EN" "http://www.springframework.org/dtd/spring-beans.dtd">
<beans>
<import resource="applicationContext.xml"></import>

</beans>
```

Web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app id="WebApp_ID" version="2.4" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd">
    <display-name>
    SpringMVC</display-name>
        <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>      
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml</param-value>  

    </context-param>

        <servlet>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>

  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.htm</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>

  <welcome-file-list>
  <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>


</web-app>
```

Comment: I really hope that you aren't seriously considering this as production code? You will run out of memory quit quickly as for each incoming request you are creating a new `ApplicationContext` which means you are creating new instances of each bean. You are already duplicating stuff by loading the same context twice you shouldn't do those things. Your point cut won't work as it will match something in the com package only not sub packages. Judging from your xml you don't have `com` package.

Comment: no i dont have com package .. please instruct what should i do

Comment: If I remove this code ----------------------------------


`<!-- AOP support -->
        <bean id="logging" class="Logging" />
        <aop:aspectj-autoproxy>
            <aop:include name='logging' />

        </aop:aspectj-autoproxy>`


from the applicationContext.xml then the program runs fine and shows the output in the webpage . but without aspect implemented ..

Comment: Please post your main Application Class.

Comment: i have posted all the codes which one do u need

Comment: What is your main executable class (with main method in it) ? Or do you deploy a war?

Comment: no main method i am running it from index.html just.i am posting the code of index.html 

`<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
<form action="hello.htm">
<input type=submit value=Click>
</form>
</body>
</html>`

Comment: from this file(index.html) i am running as Run As>Run on Server..

Comment: You only run your index.html file on server, so no depending jars are still available. You will have to build a war with all libs in it. Try use a build tool like maven.

Comment: i dont know how to use maven .. i only have option to use spring mvc with AOP

Comment: I will refer to this:
http://www.journaldev.com/2433/spring-mvc-tutorial-for-beginners-with-spring-tool-suite

Comment: The code is perfectly running but if i add this code in application context.xml : 

`<bean id="logging" class="Logging" /> `
`<aop:aspectj-autoproxy> `
<aop:include name='logging' /> 
</aop:aspectj-autoproxy>`-------------then it is not working . what should i do to resolve the issue

Comment: What does your Stack Trace (Error) say?

Comment: after i run the application the page with button "Click" comes..then i click the button and it shows 
type Status report
HTTP Status 404 - 

message 

description The requested resource () is not available. but the desired output should be 
`User Name : Tapajyoti
Age : 22 `

Comment: Please annotate your Controller Class with @Controller and add @RequestMapping(...) to handleRequest Method, delete row of code ApplicationContext context = ...

Answer (score 0):

I agree with M.Deinum, please correct these notes first of all. Further you should delete your Dispatcher-servlet.xml because you have a FileSystemXmlApplicationContext and have defined all of your beans in xml loaded there. Then please delete <listener> and <context-param> elements in web.xml and configure your aspect like this:

```
<aop:aspectj-autoproxy />
<!-- Aspect -->
<bean id="loggingAspect" class="Logging" />
```

Comment: I did just like told but a error is coming---------------------------------

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: IOException parsing XML document from ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/dispatcher-servlet.xml]; nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: Could not open ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/dispatcher-servlet.xml]
 org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:323)

Comment: Have you deleted dispatcher-servlet.xml and cleaned your project?